# Laravel + AdminLTE translate error

Tags: laravel, adminlte

I have an Laravel application with the adminlte plugin. In my local server all is working perfecly..
When I deployed my app in a remote production server the translates message doesn't work. :(

The app show me the code i have writed in my .php file instead the right message.

In "vendor\jeroennoten\laravel-adminlte\resources\lang\pt-br\adminlte.php" I have configured the message like:

```
'login_message' => 'Entre para iniciar uma nova sessão'
```

But in login page, the code:

```
<p class="login-box-msg">{{ trans('adminlte::adminlte.login_message') }}</p>
```

shows me:
adminlte::adminlte.login_message

instead:
Entre para iniciar uma nova sessão

Somebody can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the translations of `jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE` to have to run

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\ServiceProvider" --tag=translations
```

Then you have to have to edit your file in `resources/lang/vendor/adminlte/pt-br/adminlte.php` folder.

Then you can access the translation using this code

```
trans('adminlte::adminlte.login_message')
```

Comment: Ty for the help! But the provider has been published in my local server.. I have only deployed the application on a remote server and the translations stopped work! :(

Comment: In your question, you're trying to edit the file inside `vendor`, don't do that, edit the file inside `resources` folder.

Comment: Sorry bro, my mistake.. The file that I have edited is exactly this `resources/lang/vendor/adminlte/pt-br/adminlte.php` but didn't work

Comment: it is like the `trans()` helper don't work.. because the `{{ url(config('adminlte.password_reset_url', 'password/reset')) }}` link works..

Comment: @LeandroGuilhermedaSilva Did you forget to set the locale `App::setLocale('pt-br');`

Comment: @LeandroGuilhermedaSilva, I tried doing this, it works on my local.

Comment: in `config/app.php` i have setted the locale locally, before upload the application..

`'locale' => 'pt-BR'`

Comment: where you have setted this: `App::setLocale('pt-br');`?

Comment: try lowercase `'locale' => 'pt-br'` i think... try putting `App::setLocale('pt-br');` in the login controller

Comment: I have exactly the problem but in my case, the message is not pulling `vendor\acacha\admin-lte-template-laravel\resources\lang\en\message.php`. Any help pls

Answer (score 1):

Rename directory pt-br to pt-BR in resources/lang/vendor/adminlte.